# How can I update specific row in db with csv file?(rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, csv, rake, rails-activerecord

I've used csv files for initial data to MySQL database. The method below was for that import process.(I asked it before in here stackoverflow, so it might be the case that I don't understand fully this process until now..)

```
# lib/tasks/import.rake
require 'csv'

namespace :db do
  task :restaurants => :environment do
    CSV.foreach('public/seed_data/restaurants.csv') do |row|
      record = Restaurant.new(
        :name => row[0],
        :addr => row[1]
      )
      record.save!
    end
  end
end
```

But now I have to just update some specific rows which has changed after my first db import. So I just changed my first method like below. My update.csv file has id, name(updated), addr(updated) columns with no head.

```
# lib/tasks/import.rake
require 'csv'

namespace :db do
  task :restaurants_update => :environment do
    CSV.foreach('public/seed_data/update.csv') do |row|
      n = row[0]
      record = Restaurant.find(n)
      record.update_attributes(
        :name => row[1],
        :addr => row[2]
      )
      record.save!
    end
  end
end
```

I thought it can read specific rows with row[0] which has restaurant_id to update, then update name and address with the followings(row[1] and row[2]). However when I do `rake db:restaurants_update`, it's saying **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Restaurant with id=1000001**(it is my first row in csv file and my database has this record with id 1000001. I checked it out in console `Restaurant.find(1000001)`). I think import.rake might be missing my records.(can't read existing databases?)

Can anyone point out my faults?

Comment: I am not sure but, can u try using `Restaurant.find_by_id(n)`, I think the values stored in CSV is different format

Comment: you can check the value of row[0], row is a hash so  `r_hash = row.to_hash, rest = Restaurant.where(id: r_hash["id"]), rest.first.update_attributes(r_hash)`

Comment: @Sontya I tried what you said and got this `NoMethodError: undefined method to_hash for ["1000001", nil, nil]:Array`. Is it right? and I got `NoMethodError: undefined method 'update_attributes' for nil:NilClass` when I tried `find_by_id(n)`

Comment: sorry dude my bad, row is an array `n = row[0], record = Restaurant.where(id: n),  record.first.update_attributes(attributes u want to update)`, try this if it works for u

Comment: Thanks to your comments before, I could try that also(I had no idea that the finding method can make some problem). But the same error **no method for nil** pops up............................  Is there any other suggestions to look for?

Comment: I think that is the reason bcoz u r getting this error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Restaurant with id=1000001`

Comment: That's the most strange thing because my database has a record with that id exactly. . .

Answer (score 0):

If you are only updating, use `find_by(id: n)`. Personally, I'd recommend `find_or_create_by`, which would either update the field or create a new one if it's not present.

```
# lib/tasks/import.rake
require 'csv'

namespace :db do
  task :restaurants_update => :environment do
    CSV.foreach('public/seed_data/update.csv') do |row|
      n = row[0]
      record = Restaurant.find_or_create_by(id: n)
      record.update_attributes(
        :name => row[1],
        :addr => row[2]
      )
      record.save!
    end
  end
end
```